# R How to turn a dataframe within a list into new columns?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list called **list** that looks as follows:

```
Col1  Col2   Col3                    Col4        Col5   ...
1     Name1  <data.frame [1 × 3]>    <chr [0]>   <list [0]>
2     Name2  <data.frame [29 × 3]>   <chr [1]>   <data.frame [1 × 9]>
3     Name3  <data.frame [5 × 3]>    <chr [1]>   <NULL>
...
```

I want to clean up this list, turn it into a dataframe and make new columns out of the nested dataframes, lists and characters but I am not sure what is contained in them and what they look like. So my output should essentially create new columns behind *Col3* for the respective data that is contained in *Col3* and so on.

I am not sure how to accomplish this or how to build a reference of this list to attach here for people to try out. Grateful for any tips!

EDIT: Here is the dput for the first 2 rows (sanitized due to personal information)

```
structure(list(about = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), avatar = c("LINK", 
"LINK2"
), avatar_cached = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), certifications = list(
    structure(list(meta = "Issued Apr 2009", subtitle = "The Prince2 Academy", 
        title = "Prince2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")), 
    city = c("Ireland", "Greater Sydney Area"), country_code = c("IE", 
    "AU"), courses = list(structure(list(subtitle = "-", title = "TITLE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")), 
    current_company = structure(list(name = c("", "COMPANY1"
    ), company_id = c(NA, "company1"), industry = c(NA, "Capital Markets"
    ), link = c(NA, "COMPANYURL"
    )), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), `current_company:name` = c("", 
    "COMPANY1"), education = list(structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")), 
    educations_details = list(character(0), character(0)), experience = list(
        structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(company = "COMPANY1", company_id = "company1", 
            industry = "Capital Markets", location = "", positions = list(
                structure(list(description = "", duration = "Jun 2007 - Present 14 years 4 months", 
                  duration_short = "14 years 4 months", end_date = "Present", 
                  start_date = "Jun 2007", subtitle = "Company1", 
                  title = "TITLE1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
            url = "URL"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    following = c(500L, 1L), groups = list(structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")), 
    id = c("ID1", "ID2"
    ), languages = list(structure(list(subtitle = "-", title = "French"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")), 
    name = c("Name1", "Name2"), people_also_viewed = list(
        structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(), names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame")), 
    position = c(NA, "Position1"
    ), posts = list(structure(list(attribution = c("", "", ""
    ), title = c("", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L)), structure(list(attribution = "Liked by x", 
        img = "URL", 
        link = "URL", 
        title = "TITLE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    recommendations = list("“Rec”", 
        list()), recommendations_count = c(1L, NA), region = c("EU", 
    "OC"), timestamp = c("2021-07-09", "2021-09-09"), url = c("URL1", 
    "URL2"
    ), volunteer_experience = list(list(), list()), changelog = list(
        NULL, list()), `current_company:company_id` = c(NA, "company1"
    ), `current_company:industry` = c(NA, "Capital Markets")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you share the code to create your dataframe? you can do `dput(head(your_df))`

Comment: I added the dput for the first 2 rows (sanitized) - does that help? @Maël

Comment: To have more chance to get people answer, you should provide a minimal example, namely one that reproduces your problem but with minimum data frame. I'll advise to take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. You could also show what is your expected output.

Comment: Thank you @Maël - is the dput I provided sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

The `map_df()` function from the `purrr` library will work. Use the `map_df()` function for mapping the function to every element of the list, then binding the results into a single data Frame-something like this:

```
library(purrr)
# This is afunction to extract the columns from the nested data frame
## Checking if x is a df and extracts the columns
extract_cols <- function(x) {
  if (is.data.frame(x)) {
    return(x)
  }
}

# Apply the function to each element of the list
df <- map_df(list, extract_cols, .id = "id")
```

Comment: Thank you but I get the error Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'x' not found

Comment: I just edited the answer. You can re-try.

Comment: Somehow this only returns a df with 5 columns - so basically one of the dataframes within the list, but not the full dataframe

Comment: Let me recheck.